# Filemaker in iOS 5.1

Tags: ios

Is this possible to convert a Filemaker Pro DB to SQLite or other type for manipulate it in a iOS 5.1 application?

Thank you

Comment: If you just want to do a straight data conversion, try http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=filemaker+convert+sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible!  How to do it is another story for another site.